# White screen in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm a very beginner in Android. I would like to print this in TextView, but the screen is all white and i can't see content of TextView. In the console works properly. Below is my activity and layout file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 Fruits();


}

public void Fruits() {

    textView= findViewById(R.id.pa);


    String[] fruit = {"orange", "apple", "pear", "bannana", "strawberry", "mango","grape","lemon"};
    Random numberGenerator = new Random();
    /* Generate A Random Number */
    int nextRandom = numberGenerator.nextInt(fruit.length)
    ;
    Set<Integer> validate = new HashSet<>();
    /* Add First Randomly Genrated Number To Set */
    validate.add(nextRandom);
    for (int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
        /* Generate Randoms Till You Find A Unique Random Number */
        while(validate.contains(nextRandom)) {
            nextRandom = numberGenerator.nextInt(fruit.length);
        }
        /* Add Newly Found Random Number To Validate */
        validate.add(nextRandom);
        System.out.println(fruit[nextRandom]);
        textView.setText(fruit[nextRandom]);


    }


}
}
```

**layout**

```
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Hi, can you please show the  activity_main xml  file?

Comment: @Sz-Nika Janos sure

Comment: Do you want to print them all? Your code shows only one random text, which is added to the set lastly. Cause you have only one `TextView` and its value is changed every time, not appended.

Comment: I would like to show only one element

Comment: It seems you went into infinity loop. Isn't it? I guess you should get `nextRandom` inside the loop after all loop's logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is an infinite loop as the validate set would contains all 8 values at one point and will always be true. Because of which your textView is never set and keep on setting again and again.

add an additional check for size of set in while loop :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
            /* Generate Randoms Till You Find A Unique Random Number */
            while(validate.size() != fruit.length && validate.contains(nextRandom)) {
                nextRandom = numberGenerator.nextInt(fruit.length);
            }
            /* Add Newly Found Random Number To Validate */
            validate.add(nextRandom);
           Log.i("HELLO",fruit[nextRandom]);
            textView.setText(fruit[nextRandom]);
        }
```

The above will print the randomly picked fruit and will skip once validate is full.

Note : I have added an additional check of set size(just as an example), you can add your breakpoint on which you have to be out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will repeat forever. 
When `i` equal `fruit.length-1`, `validate` has stored numbers in range [0,fruit.length), it led the condition in the while loop always true, and program can not get out the loop cause nextNumber you generated inside the while loop always in range [0,fruit.length). For simpler, let imagine the `fruit` array has only one element.